# How to quote column names with Zend_Db?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I am using `key` as a column name in a MySQL table.

Since this is reserved, it needs to be escaped properly to be used in a query:

```
… WHERE `key` = 'test'
```

Manually this is no problem, but I am using the Zend Framework and want to have it handle the escape correctly, like this:

```
$table = new Application_Model_ATable();
$table->fetchRow ( $table->select()->where('key = ?','test') );
```

So the question is:

How to quote/escape column names with Zend_Db_Table?

Comment: hm, that's strange... It should have worked... Well, I don't have time to inspect ZF sources, sorry then... PS: as a workaround you could just do that manually: $table->fetchRow ( $table->select()->where('` key ` = ?','test') ); (added spaces around `key` because SO highlights it otherwise)

Comment: I am doing exactly that workaround at the moment, but was looking for a "cleaner" solution :-) Thank you for trying! :-)

Comment: If there will be a valid answer - please ping me with comment started with my name, I'm curious of "right" way of doing that ;-)

Comment: I think problem is that `key` is the reserved word in MySQL. Try specifying it as $table->select()->where('\`key\` = ?','test')

Comment: @zysoft: haha, captain to the rescue

Comment: @RockyFord: yep, thanks. I knew it is something like `quoteIdentifier` but couldn't recall it

Comment: @zerkms: $table->fetchRow ( $table->select()->where($table->getAdapter()->quoteIdentifier('key') . ' = ?','test') ); was it :-)

Comment: @favo: yep, and this made the string twice longer ;-) I would personally go with quoting field manually in this particular case

Comment: @zerkms: yes, looks nicer – if i should use dynamic columns in the future i now have at least a nice solution :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[avoiding MySQL injections with the Zend_Db class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975009/avoiding-mysql-injections-with-the-zend-db-class)

The guy explains it here actually but ill just pull out the quote quickly...

> Any other part of that expression that needs to be quoted or delimited
>   is your responsibility. E.g., if you interpolate any PHP variables
>   into the expression, safety is your responsibility. If you have column
>   names that are SQL keywords, you need to delimit them yourself with
>   quoteIdentifier(). Example:

```
$select->where($db->quoteIdentifier('order').'=?', $myVariable)
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
$table = new Application_Model_ATable();
$where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('key = ?', 'test');
$table->fetchRow ( $where );
```

> ***--excerpt from Zend_Db_Table reference--***
>   Note  The values and identifiers in the SQL expression are not quoted for you. If you have
>   values or identifiers that require quoting, you are responsible for
>   doing this. Use the quote(), quoteInto(), and quoteIdentifier()
>   methods of the database adapter.

Comment: This does not escape the column name "key", it stays untouched but you provided the answer by quoting some of the documentation. The solution is: $table->fetchRow ( $table->select()->where($table->getAdapter()->quoteIdentifier('key') . ' = ?','test') ); – Thank you!

Comment: quoteIdentifier() method is key to success here

Answer (score 1):

One must quote column names when uppercase letters have been used. It is usefull to quote those names with $db->quoteIdentifier($columnName) when you plan to switch databese adapter in the future.