# ZEND_DB_TABLE_ABSTRACT methods SQL INJECTION

Tags: sql, zend-framework, methods, sql-injection, zend-db

Is it possible for to sql inject a `ZEND_DB_TABLE_ABSTRACT` method?

like for example

```
 $this->insert();
```

*edit for a more clearer explanation*

Post values are :

`'username' = 'admin';`

`'password' = '1;Drop table users;'`

Here is the insert statement in the controller:

```
public function InsertAction() {
    $postValues =   $this->_request->getPost();
    $usersTable = new Application_Models_DbTable_Users();
    $username = $postValues['username'];
    $password = $postValues['password'];
    $data = array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password);
    $users->insert($data);
}
```

Comment: can you be little more clear with your code and explanation?

Comment: if you create your own model class that "extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract" , you can add any methods you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but in the usual uses of `insert()` it's not probable. Unless you are using `Zend_Db_Expr`, you should be safe, because `insert()` uses prepared statements.

See [this post from Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975009/avoiding-mysql-injections-with-the-zend-db-class/985316#985316) for other methods and details.

Answer (score 0):

Check the manual of Zend [Zend_Db_Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html)

It will show you who you can create your own method.